# Breaking a line every 46 characters using Javascript

Tags: javascript, line, break

Im trying to use the following code lines in order to check whether or not the string is larger than 46 characters. If it is longer, it'll break a new line every 46 characters, however, i'm failing to do so.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```html
function ContentFormat(content)
{
    var start = "";
    var end = "";
    var space = "<br/>&nbsp; &nbsp;";
    var newcontent = "";
    var toadd = "";
    if (content.length > 46)
    {
        for (var i = 0, len = content.length; i < len; i++) {
            if(i/46 == 0)
            {
                start = content.slice(0, i);
                end = content.slice(i);
                toadd = start.concat(space, end);
            }
            newcontent = toadd;
            toadd = "";
        }
    }
    return newcontent;
}
```

Comment: if(i/46 == 0) should probably read if(i%46==0)

Answer (score 0):

## You are doing wrong in for loop & if condition.

```
function ContentFormat(content)
{
    var start = "";
    var end = "";
    var space = "<br/>&nbsp; &nbsp;";
    var newcontent = "";
    var toadd = "";
    var len = content.length
    if (len > 46)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if(i%46 == 0)
            {
                start = content.slice(0, i);
                end = content.slice(i);
                toadd = start.concat(space, end);
            }
            newcontent = toadd;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is *completely wrong*, use below code instead of yours to add the break after 46 characters!

```
function ContentFormat(content)
{
    var leftPortion = "";
    var space = "<br/>&nbsp; &nbsp;";
    var newcontent = "";
    while (content.length > 46)
    {
        leftPortion = content.slice(0, 45);
        content = content.slice(45);
        newcontent = newcontent + leftPortion + space;
    }
    newcontent = newcontent + content;
    window.alert(newcontent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achived with Regular Expressions and the String.replace method.

```js
var str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';

function breakEvery(str, interval, breaker) {
    if (str === void 0) { str = ""; }
    if (interval === void 0) { interval = 0; }
    if (breaker === void 0) { breaker = "\n"; }
    if (str.length < interval) {
        return str;
    }
    var re = new RegExp('.{' + interval + '}', "ig");
    return str.replace(re, function (part) { return part + breaker; });
}

console.log(breakEvery(str, 46, "\n<br/>&nbsp; &nbsp;"));
```